# Make the object stay at the centre of the video

Tags: after-effects, premiere

I have a video with person moving around. But I need to make it so that the camera focuses on the person and ultimately the person stays in the center of the shot.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you re-shoot? What are your source and target resolutions? Can you share a sample of the video? What tools do you know how to use?

Answer (score 1):

You can make it with [tracking](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/tracking-stabilizing-motion-cs5.html). Find static point on person, and track from it. Better to use chest (not face), because it is more stable, when person moving.

But you need to understand, that you will have some empty space on the edges of the screen after that. If it is not recorded on green/blue screen, you may need to zoom your video. Because of that you will lose some quality.

Comment: no thats exactly what Im looking for. not worried about the empty space at all. I already tried tracking, but getting the points I couldnt really understand how to center the person. Could you elaborate on that a little?

Comment: You can see example here: https://youtu.be/kc7wPh6dKfs